# How can I overlap bottom navigation with content in xamarin shell tabbar

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppShell), typeof(CustomShellRenderer))]
namespace App4.Droid
{
    public class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
         public CustomShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
         {
         }

         protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
         {
             return new CustomShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker();
         }
     }

     public class CustomShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker : IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
     {
         public void Dispose()
         {
         }

         public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
         {
         }

         public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
         {
             (bottomView.Parent as LinearLayout)?.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent.ToAndroid());

              bottomView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent.ToAndroid());
              bottomView.LabelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LabelVisibilityUnlabeled;
         }
     }
}
```

[image]

shell customrenderer in android

I want to overlap the content part and bottom navigation part

I know how to implement purely XAML-only without shell and CustomRender, but I don't want to. Because my project is highly dependent on Shell

ex)
[image]

https://github.com/naweed/MauiPlanets

above app is overlap bottom navigation and contentpage
in my case remove tabbar background and remain icons
Simply put, I would like to lower the height of the content page overlapping with the bottom navigation.

Comment: Do you want to hide the bottom navigation or something else? Please provide the relevant sketch map.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT
 added more detail explain

Comment: In order to implement a custom navigation tab like that, you have to switch ContentViews, and not by switching ContentPages. Honestly, it's not a native UI design, and Apple (Human Interface Guidelines) & Android (Material Design) do not recommend not using it. https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/navigation-and-search/tab-bars/ Designers try to look cool by doing these things but it's not how apps are meant to be designed, it works well for web though

Comment: yes i agree with your opinion, i suggest to our desinger to new desgin base on giudelines, successfully changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full screen should be able to meet your need, if I understand correctly.

Add this to your `MainActivity.cs`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...

    IWindowInsetsController wicController = Window.InsetsController;
    Window.SetDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
    Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);

    if (wicController != null)
    {
       wicController.Hide(WindowInsets.Type.NavigationBars());
    }
           
}
```

Comment: sadly i suggested my designer to desgin, then not implement this ui... :(
but this solution work well